# python import specific file

Tags: python, import

trying to import a specific file called `environment.py`
the issue is that I have this file in more than one location
the way i'm loading all my file variables (more than 20 variables in each file) is :

`from environment import *`

the thing is , I have the `environment.py` in 2 directories and my `sys.path` includes both of them. python loads the file from the first location in the list.

Tried

```
import os, sys, imp
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
file = path + '/environment.py'
foo = imp.load_source('*',file)
```

But then my variables are loaded into `foo` and not directly.

Any ideas how to force `import *` from the right location

Comment: You can modify `sys.path` to place the desired directory first before doing the import.

Comment: This is just one more reason not to use `import *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to continue with what you started and this is in the global scope, you could add this to the end:

```
for varName in dir(foo):
    globals()[varName] = getattr(foo, varName)
```

Now all of the variables that were defined in `environment.py` are in your global namespace.

Although it's probably easier to just do what Tom Karzes suggested and do:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.insert(0, path)
from environment import *

# Optional. Probably harmless to leave it in your path.
del sys.path[0]
```

Comment: The first solution worked, but the second one just imported the wrong `environment` file. I also tried `sys.path.append(path)`

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a module

```
/module
    __init__.py
    environment.py
```

That way you can call

```
from module.environment import *
```

And there should be no issue having two modules with `environment.py` in them, the only difference being the import call. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Isn't the `module` folder actually a python package here? i.e. a module is usually a python file, like `environment.py` and `__init__.py`, in this example. Also, you will run into headaches if the package and module have the same name - so `environment` package with an `environment.py` module will break import sometimes (or maybe always?).  Also, with the latest python versions, if your package is a folder inside another package, you don't need the `__init__.py`.